# Laravel Eloquent doesn't save model to the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I want to create a record on the database with eloquent but it keeps telling me this error :

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in /path/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 681 in /path/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Grammar.php:135
```

I have logged data to be inserted :

```
array (
  'text_id' => 12,
  'user_id' => 2,
  'spots' => 
  array (
    0 => 'a',
    1 => 'd',
    2 => 'd',
    3 => 'r',
    4 => 'g',
    5 => 'h',
    6 => 'w'
  ),
  'type' => 'long',// error is on this field
)
```

**it stops at the type field**

My table columns & types :

```
'text_id' => INT,
'user_id' => INT,
'spots' => JSON,
'type' => VARCHAR(256),
'updated_at' => DATETIME
'created_at' => DATETIME
```

when does this happen ?

Comment: try change the name of column **type** to something else

Comment: @MohamedSabil83 nothing changed

Comment: Can you show your database columns with types?

Comment: Is `spots` a JSON column that your using Laravel Model `$casts` property to cast to JSON? If not this will be your issue. It cannot save an array to the database. Edit: I see `spots` is a JSON column, are you casting?

Comment: do what @PatrykWoziński say and paste the Model and store function

Comment: @Jono20201 You were right . post an answer please

Comment: @Ramin posted, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model you need to cast `type` to JSON.

```
protected $casts = [
    'type' => 'json',
];
```